# Pandas: How to convert months since epoch to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

If I have a dataframe with datetime:

```
df = pd.to_datetime([1, 32], unit='d',
           origin=pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01'))
df
>> DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-02', '2022-02-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I can then retrieve the number of months since the epoch using:

```
df.to_period('M').astype(int)
>> Int64Index([624, 625], dtype='int64')
```

However, I would like to go the other way, e.g. to convert month number 624:

```
pd.to_datetime(624, format='%?')
```

Is this possible?  What format will I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to add the `DateOffset` to the epoch `Timestamp`. Note: Here you will be loosing the day precision since there is no way for us to tell the exact day on the basis of only month number.

```
pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01') + pd.DateOffset(months=624)
```

Result

```
Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00')
```